# When switching to a new wordpress folder structure, I get "Could not open file!" error when adding post

Tags: php, wordpress, git, wordpress-theming

I am changing the file structure of my wp installation to allow for version control and using wordpress as a git submodule. Everything seems to function fine with this change (see below) except I get "Could not open file!" error when I add post. this happens with any post-type i try (I have 3 different ones) It appears the error is happening at get_default_post_to_edit() in the file "post-new.php". Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Old File Structure:

```
 wp-admin
 wp-content
 wp-includes
 etc...
```

New File Structure:

```
 content
      themes
      plugins
      uploads
 wp (git submodule)
      wp-admin
      wp-content
      wp-includes
      etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is only an issue when you are logged into wordpress and viewing the site with the top admin Wordpress bar. Otherwise it functions normally.